Passing Data Class Properties as Parameters in Function without Redundancy in Kotlin
I have a data class representing user settings:
@Serializable
data class UpdateSettingsRequest(
    val isNotificationsOn: Boolean?,
    val isDarkMode: Boolean?,
    val language: String?,
    val isAnimationsEnabled: Boolean?,
)

And a repository function to update these settings:
class SettingsRepository {
    fun updateSettings(request: UpdateSettingsRequest) {
        makeNetworkRequest(request)
    }

    private fun makeNetworkRequest(request: UpdateSettingsRequest) {
        TODO("make network request to update settings. request = $request")
    }
}

Currently, I use the repository like this:
fun main() {
    val repo = getSettingsRepository()
    repo.updateSettings(UpdateSettingsRequest(isNotificationsOn = false))
    // In null cases it will ignore updating those fields.
}

However, I want to avoid creating UpdateSettingsRequest instances outside the repository, so I changed updateSettings to accept individual parameters:
class SettingsRepository {
    fun updateSettings(
        isNotificationsOn: Boolean? = null,
        isDarkMode: Boolean? = null,
        language: String? = null,
        isAnimationsEnabled: Boolean? = null,
    ) {
        val request = UpdateSettingsRequest(
            isNotificationsOn = isNotificationsOn,
            isDarkMode = isDarkMode,
            language = language,
            isAnimationsEnabled = isAnimationsEnabled,
        )
        makeNetworkRequest(request)
    }

    private fun makeNetworkRequest(request: UpdateSettingsRequest) {
        TODO("make network request to update settings. request = $request")
    }
}

This approach allows me to call the function more cleanly:
fun main() {
    val repo = getSettingsRepository()
    repo.updateSettings(isNotificationsOn = false)
}

However, if I add new properties to UpdateSettingsRequest, I'll need to update updateSettings each time, which is error-prone.
Question: Is there a more maintainable approach in Kotlin that would allow me to handle this without duplicating properties in updateSettings?

Why do you think it's error prone? If you update UpdateSettingsRequest and add a new property with a default, your repository function will use that default until you change it in repo.updateSettings. That doesn't sound error-prone, but just evolutionary change. Eventually, you'll want to set the new property and the only way to do so is to change updateSettings. Also, if you don't have a default, it will be a compilation error so you'll have to add it to the function anyway.

"I want to avoid creating UpdateSettingsRequest instances outside the repository" Why?

When isAnimationsEnabled was already set to false in a previous call and you now call repo.updateSettings(isNotificationsOn = false), it does not only set isNotificationsOn to false, it also resets isAnimationsEnabled back to true. This doesn't seem to be what you want. I'm with @Sweeper here: What's the issue with encapsulating the settings in a data class, outside of the repo?

In fact, it may be better if you have a separate updateSettings function for each setting you want to update. If you had the settings encapsulated in a data class outside of the repo as @tyg suggests, you would have a local copy of the settings. But the settings in the DB may have been altered by another process. If you then update isNotificationsOn, you will also reset isAnimationsEnabled back to what it was in your current process, even though another process may have changed it in the DB. It might be better to have an SQL query that modifies only those settings you want to modify.

@Sweeper Because its a DTO object contains Gson serialization annotations. i dont want to create another data class and map it to network dto

@tyg u r right. my bad. actually i wrote an example and the real implementation was not like this. in real implementation, those fields are nullable and their default values are null. and if u pass null they will not change the behavior. i will edit my question

@k314159 I edited my question, it had issues. Now fields are null by default and in null cases they will not get updated.

Other have posted their opinions in the comments. One solution  would be to make the data class parameters as var
Now inside the SettingsRepository you can do:
companion object {
    inline fun buildRequest(request: UpdateSettingsRequest.() -> Unit): UpdateSettingsRequest {
        return UpdateSettingsRequest().apply(request)
    }
}

After that you should be be able to call:
repo.updateSettings(SettingsRepository.buildRequest {
    isNotificationsOn = false
    language = "en-us"
})

Note that make the parameter var may not be desirable in some cases.
